# css: how to have 2nd class unset value of first

Tags: css

I have a div that always has the `container` class.  It has a max height of 400px.  There are some instances where it has a `special` class, in which case it should take a 100% height and ignore the max-height rule but it's currently adhering to max-height.

```
<div class="container special">

</div>

.container {
  max-height: 400px;
    
    &.special {
       height: 100%
    }
}
```

Is the best way to handle this set it back to the initial value?  :

```
.container {
  max-height: 400px;

    &.special {
       max-height: initial;
       height: 100%
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `max-height: initial;`, can't you set as `max-height: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

> u should use breakpoints for special case like on specific resolution and add the css in the breakpoint u like such as different height

Answer (score 0):

You can go for `id="YourID"` for a overriding class.

give some those `special` instances an id

There is a pointsystem in css:

"If the element has inline styling, that automatically1 wins (1,0,0,0 points)
For each ID value, apply 0,1,0,0 points
For each class value (or pseudo-class or attribute selector), apply 0,0,1,0 points
For each element reference, apply 0,0,0,1 point"

~https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

so the bigger "point value" you use the more important those porperites are overriding the others with lower point value

Comment: This solves the problem only if there is one such `div`. You can't assign the same `id` to multiple divs

Answer (score 0):

For all the divs that have the `special` class, you can use the `!important` rule. Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp).

```
.container {
    max-height: 400px;
}

.special {
    max-height: none !important;
    height: 100%
}
```

Comment: you shouldnt use !important, it's the last resort;